# "in favor" used adverbially

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, ellipses, adverb-position

I'd like to know whether the phrase "in favor" can be used adverbially, e.g. *They all voted in favor*.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you meant can  *they all voted in favor* be used without *of  [something]*, then I believe the answer is no.

Comment: @michael.hor257k It can be used like that if the context is clear. For instance: "The committee were asked to accept the minutes of the previous meeting. They all voted in favour."

Comment: @BoldBen It doesn't sound right to me - and the dictionaries seem to support me on this. OTOH, *all those in favor* can be used on its own.

Comment: @michael.hor257k It's a common elidation, the words "of it" are omitted frequently. As it's an elidation, of course, the omitted words are _implied_ so it's not, actually, a full sentence any more that "Look out!" is a full sentence. I wonder if it's more common in the UK.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. This is a common and natural usage. 
A quick google for “voted in favour” returns many such examples.

For example, here’s a Wikipedia article with that usage in the title:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causes_of_the_vote_in_favour_of_Brexit